# Calling interface method after reflection & type switching in golang

Tags: go, methods, struct, reflection, type-switch

I have struct

```
type ChartOpts struct {
    Name              mypakage.MyType
    Repo              mypakage.MyType
}
```

Ι want to iterate over its fields and if a type assertion is satisfied, called the method on that (asserted) type.

```
func (chartOpts ChartOpts) BindFlags(cobCom *cobra.Command) {
    fields := reflect.TypeOf(chartOpts)
    values := reflect.ValueOf(chartOpts)
    num := fields.NumField()
    fmt.Println(fields, values, num)
    for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
        field := fields.Field(i)
        switch v := field.Type.(type) {
        case mypackage.MyType:
            field.BindPersistentFlag(cobCom)
        default:
            log.Fatal(ErrUnhandledType)
        }
    }
    

}
```

The above code does not compile with this error:

```
field.BindPersistentFlag undefined (type reflect.StructField has no field or method BindPersistentFlag)
```

why?

Comment: `field` is of type reflect.StructField which has no method `BindPersistentFlag`  fo obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`field` is of type [`reflect.StructField`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructField), it's not the field's value, it is its struct field descriptor.

You need to type-switch on the field's value:

```
values.Field(i)
```

Note that the above is the field's value wrapped in [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), so extract the value with [`Value.Interface()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Interface):

```
for i := 0; i < num; i++ {
    switch v := values.Field(i).Interface().(type) {
    case mypackage.MyType:
        v.BindPersistentFlag(cobCom)
    default:
        log.Fatal(ErrUnhandledType)
    }
}
```

And call `BindPersistentFlag()` on `v`, as that will be of type `mypackage.MyType` inside the `case`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the value and recover an interface out of reflect:

```
values.Field(i).Interface().(Type).Method()
```

In your case it would be simpler to switch over the interface:

```
switch v := values.Field(i).Interface().(type) {
case Type:
    v.Method()
...
```